# Sorting Search Results of a CSV file According to the Fuzzy Logic Result

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a small data-frame for myself or list of entries if you will. I want to be able to search this database for specific entries. The code works exactly the way I want it to even if it might not be the most elegant way of writing it - I am still new to python and I just found out about the csv module the other day-. I can enter a phrase and it gives me the corresponding word with the percentage value.

The file is in the form of a CSV file and I want to have the output sorted by the percentage value. So, the most relevant match should be at the top and the least relevant should be at the bottom. I am using fuzzylogic to calculate the similarities between two strings, but I have used difflib.

The end result is sorted alphabetically, but not numerically, which is my goal. I have tried using Panda, but I am getting a whole bunch of errors, probably my fault because I don't know how to use it that well, but I would like to stick to "pure" python, so to speak, at the moment because I want to get a better hang of it.

To summarise my whole question: What would be your solution for sorting the results numerically ?.

I would greatly appreciate your help and I thank you for taking the time to read this long post.

```
try:
        import csv,os,difflib,easygui,pickle,sys
        from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
        from fuzzywuzzy import process
        import operator 

except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print ("You do not have the required modules installed.The progam will now close.")
    raise SystemExit

Suche = "Kunde"
Wahrscheinlichkeit = 60

Eintrag=[]
def aehnlichkeit(a, b)  
    ergebnis = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(a,b)
    return round (ergebnis,2)
with open('Platzhalter_Message_Keys.csv', 'rt') as csvfile: 
    Column=[]
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader: 
        column=row[0],row[1],row[2]
        Column.append(column)
        eintrag=aehnlichkeit(Suche,row[1])
        Eintrag.append(eintrag)

    for Column,Eintrag in zip (Column,Eintrag): 
        if Eintrag >=Wahrscheinlichkeit:
            print([Eintrag,Column])
```

Output of the code

```
[60, (' Index', 'Index', 'Index')]
[60, (' Keine', 'Keine', 'none')]
[100, (' Kunde', 'Kunde', 'Customer')]
[67, (' Kundenname', 'Kundenname', 'CustomerName')]
[77, (' Kundennr', 'Kundennr', 'CustomerNo')]
[62, (' KurzName', 'KurzName', 'ShortName')]
[62, (' Reklamation.Kunde_Email', 'Kunde_Email', 'Customer_email')]
[62, (' Reklamation.Kunde_L_Fax', 'Kunde_L_Fax', 'Customer_S_Fax')]
[62, (' Reklamation.Kunde_L_Ort', 'Kunde_L_Ort', 'Customer_S_City')]
[62, (' Reklamation.Kunde_L_PLZ', 'Kunde_L_PLZ', 'Customer_S_ZIPCode')]
[62, (' Reklamation.Kunde_R_Fax', 'Kunde_R_Fax', 'Customer_I_Fax')]
[62, (' Reklamation.Kunde_R_Ort', 'Kunde_R_Ort', 'Customer_I_City')]
[62, (' Reklamation.Kunde_R_PLZ', 'Kunde_R_PLZ', 'Customer_I_POBox')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the results sorted, you will have to create a sorted list of them, which will require extra memory to store — your code is just iterating through a dynamically generated sequence of pairs from the two lists.

This is easy to do with the built-in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function in conjunction with [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create a `key` function to be the value to be used to order the items — as illustrated below.

I have also fixed a few other minor issues I noticed.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

HI_TO_LO = False  # Order of sorted results.
Eintrag = [60, 60, 100, 67, 77, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62]
Wahrscheinlichkeit = 60

with open('Platzhalter_Message_Keys.csv', 'rt', newline='') as csvfile:
    Column=[]

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        column = row[0], row[1], row[2]
        Column.append(column)
        # Using hardcoded values for example.
        #eintrag = aehnlichkeit(Suche, row[1])
        #Eintrag.append(eintrag)

    sorted_results = sorted(zip(Column, Eintrag), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=HI_TO_LO)
    for Column, Eintrag in sorted_results:
        if Eintrag >= Wahrscheinlichkeit:
            print([Eintrag, Column])
```

Output:

```
[60, ('Index', 'Index', 'Index')]
[60, ('Keine', 'Keine', 'none')]
[62, ('KurzName', 'KurzName', 'ShortName')]
[62, ('Reklamation.Kunde_Email', 'Kunde_Email', 'Customer_email')]
[62, ('Reklamation.Kunde_L_Fax', 'Kunde_L_Fax', 'Customer_S_Fax')]
[62, ('Reklamation.Kunde_L_Ort', 'Kunde_L_Ort', 'Customer_S_City')]
[62, ('Reklamation.Kunde_L_PLZ', 'Kunde_L_PLZ', 'Customer_S_ZIPCode')]
[62, ('Reklamation.Kunde_R_Fax', 'Kunde_R_Fax', 'Customer_I_Fax')]
[62, ('Reklamation.Kunde_R_Ort', 'Kunde_R_Ort', 'Customer_I_City')]
[62, ('Reklamation.Kunde_R_PLZ', 'Kunde_R_PLZ', 'Customer_I_POBox))')]
[67, ('Kundenname', 'Kundenname', 'CustomerName')]
[77, ('Kundennr', 'Kundennr', 'CustomerNo')]
[100, ('Kunde', 'Kunde', 'Customer')]
```

Comment: Oh, wow, I can't believe how easy that actually was. I only had to change one line in my code and I haven't been sitting here for hours trying to figure that out. Thank you very much. 

There is only one thing: is there anyway to reverse the order so that it starts at 100 and then goes to 0 ?

Comment: Yes there's a very easy way—and described in the linked documentation for `sorted()` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. I really do appreciate your help !

Comment: You're welcome. For future reference, when you ask questions here, it's best to provide code for a [mre] and simplify that as much as possible—very little of the information in your question has anything at all to do with what you wanted to know. If you do this you'll get more answers more quickly.